# Is the Death penalty really justice?

Tags: genesis, death, noah, punishment

In Genesis 9 God makes a covenant with Noah. Part of that covenant focuses on murder 9:6. What is curious to me is why enforce the penalty of murder with the death penalty when Cain was essentially let off the hook. At times God's purpose is a mystery to me and this is one of those times.

> Gen 9:6 - Whoever sheds the blood of man, by man his blood will be
> shed; for in His own image God has made mankind.

Comment: The answer to this question concerns the structure of divine covenants and their legal basis.  Any contract must include penalties must be included.  However, in the divine contracts, the aspect of divine grace must also be included.  See also Isa 45:9.  (On a personal note, I do not believe that state sanctioned murder solves the problem of murder.  One cannot use murder to cure murder; but this is not the place for such a debate.)

Comment: There was no witness to Cain's deed. And Cain did not confess to it. Later, Lamech sought to protect himself by referencing Cain when he, that is Lamech, had freely confessed to killing. It was clear that after the Flood, humanity needed to be protected from murderers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, context is crucial. Here's a larger context of God's covenant with Noah after the flood from the LXX translation of Genesis 9:3-7,9 APB:

> And every reptile [Greek, *herpeton*, a creeping thing, reptile,
> especially a serpent] which is living shall be to you for food; as I
> have given all vegetation of grass to you. Except eat not meat with
> the blood of life. For even your blood—-the blood of your lives from
> the hand of all of the wild beasts I shall require it, and from the
> hand of a man’s brother I shall require it. The one shedding blood of
> a man, in return, his blood shall be shed; for in the image of God I
> made the man. But you grow and multiply and fill the earth and
> multiply upon the earth. Behold I raise up my covenant to you and to
> your seed after you, and every living soul after you, from fowls and
> from cattle, and to all the wild beasts of the earth, as many as are
> with you, from all of the ones coming forth from out of the ark.

I've chosen to use the LXX as a snapshot of how Jewish scholars, under the auspices of the Sanhedrin, interpreted *Torah* in the third century BCE.

The elements of this legal contract include

- What humans are now allowed to eat and the restrictions on blood.
- The scope covered by these restrictions, man and animal.
- The responsibility imputed from shedding blood--by and toward man and animal.
- The reason why these restrictions are set down.
- The contextually related alternative, namely to reproduce and migrate.
- The duration and inclusivity of this contract.

What information is missing here?

Let me suggest that there's no assertion that *mankind* will be enforcing it rather than God. Read the passage again if you doubt me. Let me add that the "in return, his blood will be shed" is prophetic. It is similar to

> Then Jesus said to him, “Put your sword back into its place. For all
> who take the sword will perish by the sword." – Matthew 26:52 ESV

In the later Mosaic Law, capital-punishment enforcement is given to the people corporately, as a community rather than an individual.

Notice that humans are permitted to slaughter animals for food, but will be held responsible by God for any transgression in intent (sport hunting not done for food) and with regard to eating blood.

Hope this helps.